# Typescript ESLint Error - How can I type children when using react functional components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx-react

I am putting together a boilerplate sample of:

- React 16.x (from create-react-app)
- Typescript

  - with functional components
- Material-UI
- Mobx-React

  - via context providers
- ESLint

I have almost everything worked out, but I can't seem to figure out this one ESLint error I am getting. I have a MobX store provider that looks like this

```js
import { useLocalStore } from 'mobx-react';
import React from 'react';
import { StoreType } from '../Types/StoreType';
import { StoreContext } from './StoreContext';

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useLocalStore(() => ({
    loginStore: { email: ['neil.peart@rush.yyz'] },
    applicationStore: { firstName: 'neil', lastName: 'peart' }
  })) as StoreType;
  return <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
};
```

I am getting the error:

> 6:30  warning  Missing return type on function            @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
>
> 6:33  error    'children' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

If you want to pull the whole thing down, you can here: https://github.com/Savij/functional-react-mobx-material

Appreciate any insight!
-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `StoreProvider` in your example is a `React.ReactElement`, which can be set like so:

```
export const StoreProvider = ({ children }): React.ReactElement => {
    return ... 
}
```

The type of `children` in your source code is also `React.ReactElement`, but must be wrapped in an interface because it's getting passed in as a property of the component's props.

```
export const StoreProvider = ({ children }: StoreProviderProps): React.ReactElement => {
    return ... 
}

interface StoreProviderProps {
    children: React.ReactElement;
}
```

Comment: Lucas - I actually figured out the function return type earlier today. I had added an ignore to ESLint because it was only complaining about:
'error  'children' is missing in props validation'. I added "react/prop-types": "off" and was happy enough with it since it was no longer showing any issues in the linter. I do like the answer with the interface. It doesn't seem normal to put an interface on a method. I am used to thinking of them in the case of a class. I changed interface to type StoreProviderProps = { ... } instead, but I'm not sure if that has any implications vs interface....